# How to get snapshot of changed data and store them on daily basis

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have a requirement from my client. He wants to store a snapshot of what data has changed for some given tables, mainly financial transaction tables, on daily basis. This is for audit purposes. Data is to be stored table wise, so that we can develop some reports based on it to keep track of changes on daily basis. What are the possible techniques for this in SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition? I am also interested in the latest available version as we are planning to migrate to latest SQL Server version.

Comment: What edition of SQL server are you using - standard or enterprise? If standard then triggers and if enterprise then change data capture will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Enable Change Data Capture on the tables of interest. Copy the rows thus flagged to another table that matches the definition of the first, but with an additional datetime column to show when it was written. Essentially a slowly changing dimension, type 2 in the Kimball nomenclature.

---

SQL Server 2016 introduced [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables). These combine the features of CDC and an audit table I mention above. Once defined, the system itself copies row versions to a history table as data changes. All history is retained until explicitly deleted. Each row has a time interval recorded showing when it was valid.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) which is a light weight version of [CDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx). Or, since you didn't specify what kinds of reports and you are dealing with changes to financial data with the possibility if auditing, you should investigate [SQL Server Audit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) which gives you information on the user aspect of data access and changes.

Comment: I have not yet seen about change tracking or sql server audit yet, but it seems like CDC will solve my problem because what I want is a copy of what is changed on a given date.

Comment: If you have a heavily used OLTP system or space/ETL time constraints I'd give Change tracking another look... it's going to be easier to work with and put less stress on your systems.